# Objective-C For-In Loop Get Index

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, nsarray

Consider the following statement:

```
for (NSString *string in anArray) {

    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```

How can I get the index of `string` in `anArray` without using a traditional `for` loop and without checking the value of `string` with every object in `anArray`?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Arrays are guaranteed to iterate in object order. So:

```
NSUInteger index = 0;
for(NSString *string in anArray)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ is at index %d", string, index);

    index++;
}
```

Alternatively, use the block enumerator:

```
[anArray
    enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:
       ^(NSString *string, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop)
       {
           NSLog(@"%@ is at index %d", string, index);
       }];
```

Answer (score -6):

Try this.

```
for (NSString *string in anArray)
{
  NSUInteger index = [anArray indexOfObject:string];
}
```

Comment: `- indexOfObject` is an `O(n)` operation, so this algorithm is `O(n^2)`. It's strictly worse than incrementing an index on each iteration or using `- enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:`, both of which are still `O(n)`.

Comment: This answer is **wrong**. If `anArray` contains duplicates, the `index` for the duplicated elements would be incorrect.